# Draw 2D Text in fixed position on the display in a 3D world - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, text, 3d

I am creating a very simple OpenGL game in C++, with a 3D model moving in a 3D world. I have to put on the screen some 2D text: the camera is constantly following the model and I would like the text to appear in a fixed position with respect to the window.

I tried to use a tutorial from Nehe but, in that case, the gluLookAt is in a fixed position (looking from "high", down to the world) and text is obviously displayed correctly.

Unfortunately, I did not succeded in doing what I want with glRotatef/glTranslatef.

Can anyone help me? How can I display text in a fixed position while camera is moving?
I already looked for a solution in other threads but in no one I found a suitable solution (in particular, solutions exploiting glut function, which are very common, did not seem to work in my case).

I also premise that I already implemented all the functions to build/kill fonts etc. as explained in the Nehe tutorial I followed.

EDIT:
I attach the code I have just written. Unfortunately it does not work but I do not understand why (and actually I did not understand how raster position exactly works).

```
...
//Here I draw the rest of the scene
....
//now I try to display the text
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0.0, width, 0.0, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glRasterPos2i(100, 100);
glPrint("SAMPLE TEXT");
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: You can use a different view-matrix for rendering the text. Draw the scene first as you do it now, then change the matrices to a orthographic projection and a appropriate view matrix and draw the text.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just updated my question with the code I have written, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to use `glWindowPos()` instead of `glRasterPos()` to set the current raster position. `glWindowPos()` allows you to specify the position in window coordinates, which is in pixels.

For example, to set the position to (100, 100), with the origin being in the bottom-left corner:

```
glWindowPos2i(100, 100);
```

The current transformations do not have an impact on this call.

Comment: It is probably the solution to my problems, but I can't directly exploit it due to the unexplainable missing support to openGL from 1.2 upwards by Microsoft. I looked for some solutions on how to use it, like the last post of this discussion (http://www.gamedev.net/topic/549973-opengl--glreadpixels--and-gldrawpixels/), but though it compiles correctly after the inclusion of glew.h, I do not see any text on the screen (I used Nehe custom glPrint routine to show text)